# JQuery Hide list items more than 5 code issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
  $("ul.items").each(function() {
    $("li:gt(4)", this).hide();
  });
});
});
</script>
```

Basically it's not hidding anything...

Here is the list part of the code:

```
<ul class="items">
<li>One</li>
<li>Two</li>
<li>Three</li>
<li>Four</li>
<li>Five</li>
<li>Six</li>
<li>Seven</li>
</ul>
```

Can anyone spot the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (a lot cleaner):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       $("ul.items li:gt(4)").hide();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NLDTF/

Answer (score 1):

1. `$(document).ready(function() { //TODO Something... });`
2. `$(function(){ //TODO something });`

`2 == 1`, you should use one of them, don't write 2 into 1.